# Facebook Like, Share, Send and Comment on the same page

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-like, send

I added Facebook Like, Send, Share and Comment Box at bottom of each post of my website.

Bellow is Facebook Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=167208243474904";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Like -->
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>


<!-- Send -->
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-width="100" data-height="50" data-colorscheme="light"></div>

<!-- Share -->
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="link"></div>

<!-- Comment -->
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-numposts="5" data-width="500"></div>
```

It work properly for Facebook, but it make my website very slow and spend mush resource(Memory and CPU) on my Dedicated Server. After I disable all these Facebook plugin it load faster.

Does it cause from Facebook plugin or from wrong in code? Or other reason?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is HTML and Javascript, it doesn't run on your server.

It's likely an isolated instance of a CDN failure, or something of the sort. If it continues, use your browser's Javascript Console to track resource load times, etc. Then report that back here.